# How to randomly select the content of some cells into a data frame?

Tags: r, sample

It seems simple but I cannot find the solution: I want to randomly select some elements into a data frame imported from a .xlsx file.Is there a function such as sample_n to do this?

My problem lies in the fact that `sample_n` returns a number of **whole rows** and not **single data**. That is: I want a sample of elements into whatever (and possibly repeated) row.

Here is an example:

```
    MAS<-function(x,n){sample_n(x, n, na.rm=FALSE)}
df <- data.frame(
  "entero" = 1:4, 
  "factor" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
  "numero" = c(NA, 3.4, NA, 5.6),
  "cadena" = as.character(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
)
MAS(df,2)
```

which returns, for example:

```
      entero factor numero cadena
1      3      c     NA      c
2      4      d    5.6      d
```

That is, whole rows instead of single elements. I would also like to avoid the 'NA' values, by the way.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code and data using `dput`?

Comment: Do you want to sample values from random rows and columns? (eg entero from row 1 but factor from row 2, for example)  Why not pivot your data longer to get a data frame with columns row, column, value and `sample_n` from that?  Also, think about how to return values from columns of different classes.

Comment: I want the function to pick whatever element into the data frame, even repeated row or column.

Comment: Do you need to keep the original class (`character`, `numeric`, etc), or is it OK if you coerce it all to `character`?

Comment: No. I don't need to keep the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind getting a `character` vector, it is as simple as coercing the `data.frame` into a (`character`) `matrix` and then sampling from it:

```
ddff <- as.matrix(df)
sample(ddff, 2)
```

To avoid sampling `NA` values, just restrict the sampling to the cells which aren't missing:

```
sample(ddff[!is.na(ddff)], 2)
```

If you want to keep the `class`, you'll need to get a `list` in return, and the sampling gets a bit trickier.